# Error with apt upgrade pakage linux-image-5.13.0-41-generic

Tags: upgrade

After running:

```
sudo apt update
```

&

```
sudo apt upgrade
```

I get the following error:

```
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-5.13.0-41-generic linux-hwe-5.13-headers-5.13.0-41
  linux-image-5.13.0-41-generic linux-modules-5.13.0-41-generic
  linux-modules-extra-5.13.0-41-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up linux-image-5.13.0-48-generic (5.13.0-48.54~20.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for linux-image-5.13.0-48-generic (5.13.0-48.54~20.04.1) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-48-generic
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub:
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 52: .: Can't open /usr/local/share/openocd/grub-mkconfig_lib
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-5.13.0-48-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-5.13.0-48-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-5.13.0-48-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have also `run apt autoremove`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-headers-5.13.0-41-generic linux-hwe-5.13-headers-5.13.0-41
  linux-image-5.13.0-41-generic linux-modules-5.13.0-41-generic
  linux-modules-extra-5.13.0-41-generic
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 5 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 508 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 295730 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-headers-5.13.0-41-generic (5.13.0-41.46~20.04.1) ...
Removing linux-hwe-5.13-headers-5.13.0-41 (5.13.0-41.46~20.04.1) ...
Removing linux-modules-extra-5.13.0-41-generic (5.13.0-41.46~20.04.1) ...
Removing linux-image-5.13.0-41-generic (5.13.0-41.46~20.04.1) ...
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-41-generic
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub:
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 52: .: Can't open /usr/local/share/openocd/grub-mkconfi
g_lib
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-5.13.0-41-generic (--remove):
 installed linux-image-5.13.0-41-generic package post-removal script subprocess 
returned error exit status 1
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-5.13.0-41-generic
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
```

which I also attempted to fix with `sudo apt --fix-broken install`:

```
this the same results: 
eading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  linux-image-unsigned-5.13.0-41-generic
Suggested packages:
  fdutils linux-doc | linux-hwe-5.13-source-5.13.0 linux-hwe-5.13-tools
  linux-headers-5.13.0-41-generic linux-modules-extra-5.13.0-41-generic
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-image-5.13.0-41-generic
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-image-unsigned-5.13.0-41-generic
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 10.1 MB of archives.
After this operation, 283 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 linux-image-unsigned-5.13.0-41-generic amd64 5.13.0-41.46~20.04.1 [10.1 MB]
Fetched 10.1 MB in 1s (8,361 kB/s)                              
dpkg: linux-image-5.13.0-41-generic: dependency problems, but removing anyway as
 you requested:
 linux-modules-5.13.0-41-generic depends on linux-image-5.13.0-41-generic | linu
x-image-unsigned-5.13.0-41-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-5.13.0-41-generic is to be removed.
  Package linux-image-unsigned-5.13.0-41-generic is not installed.

(Reading database ... 262041 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-5.13.0-41-generic (5.13.0-41.46~20.04.1) ...
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-41-generic
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub:
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 52: .: Can't open /usr/local/share/openocd/grub-mkconfi
g_lib
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-5.13.0-41-generic (--remove):
 installed linux-image-5.13.0-41-generic package post-removal script subprocess 
returned error exit status 1
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-5.13.0-41-generic
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Any recommendations to fix the issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Something is setting your `pkgdatadir` environment variable to `/usr/local/share/openocd`. Does that directory exist at all? Did you by any chance install OpenOCD in the past and then remove it without cleanly uninstalling it?

Comment: Hello @Tilman yes, that was my issue, something when wrong with Zsh in the install, it cleaned my profile scripts and edit many environment variables, rebooted and it all works now. Apologies as I looked at the message and troubleshooted in the same direction of you comment, but did not get online here until now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had an issue with my environment variables after Zsh install and my own customization of my shell profiles scripts, the pkgdatadir was riddled with errors and removing unknown paths allowed it to fix the problem.